# Geotagging data questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, data

When a user uses the tag `data` to ask a question about a specific area ( `<` the entire world), would it make sense to allow some coordinates to be associated with the question? For example a small map could appear and the user could place a point, or draw a bounding box to show the area that they are interested in.

Examples of questions where this might be of use:

- [Looking for GIS data for Curitiba, Brazil?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34495/gis-data-for-curitiba-brazil)
- [Seeking shapefiles for New Zealand Cities and Suburbs/Neighbourhoods?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/where-can-i-find-shapefiles-for-new-zealand-cities-and-suburbs-neighbourhoods)
- [Seeking European City boundary data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33148/where-can-i-find-european-city-boundary-data)

I think this would be a valuable addition to facilitate searching for data sources. One way to  implement this could be a tag `data-specific` which could have lat/long as part of the tag definition; for example `data-specific-31.4-0.34`. This would enable interesting maps to made using the API to show data sources for around the world.

Comment: Nice idea. However, would the latlon part of the tag not lead to a huge number of tags, particularly if people use finer resolutions (e.g. 31.42-0.349) for a similar area? Or is there a way to capture coordinates in a 'sub-tag'?

Comment: True; I was hoping only the first part would be used as a tag in it's current form, and rest could be stored like an attribute within a tag. Not sure if such an approach is possible.

Comment: I've set this to [meta-tag:status-declined] because it would result in a limitless number of tags.  For any geotagging of questions to be implemented in the SE engine would require researching/asking for a feature request on [meta.se] rather than on a site-specific meta like ours.

Comment: Actually we already have a collection of such tags. Your first example should have been tagged [tag:brazil]; the second [tag:new-zealand]. The third is already tagged [tag:europe]. Generally speaking, though they're not all linked together, there are tags that can narrow locations. They often start at the continent level, or a region thereof, and go to the country level. Much more detailed than that and you end up with a bunch tags that are probably too specific to really be useful (for example there are no tags for each US state, or Chinese provinces, or individual cities as far as I know).

Comment: I guess it now exists. I asked this question almost four years ago!

Answer (score 1):

Open Street Map supports Bounding Boxes

Example (Greater London, UK)

http://www.openstreetmap.org/?minlon=-0.489&minlat=51.28&maxlon=0.236&maxlat=51.686&box=yes

Comment: Yes, however my post is more about having some way of keeping track of data sources for different locations.